# Integrating native JavaScript classes in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, class, angularjs, instance

I have a native JavaScript class:

```js
var Holder = new function(elements) {

    this.elements = elements;

    this.anyFunction() {
        // use of this.elements
    };

};
```

How to use it in an Angular-way? For example, if I would like to use:

```js
.controller('AnyController', ['Holder',
function (Holder) {

    var elements = [
        {id: 1, label: 'foo'},
        {id: 2, label: 'bar'}
    ];

    $scope.holder = new Holder(elements);

}])
```

How should I register my `Holder` class then? What are the options (if any)?

In parallel, is it *that bad* to use native JavaScript classes in an Angular app (i.e. without integrating it within the framework)?

Comment: Why not create it as a service? The `.service` method can take a class. Check out tutorials on how to do it with Coffeescript where they uses classes, then look at the compiled JavaScript.

Comment: @elclanrs If I understood services correctly, *all Angular services are application singletons* (see [AngularJS: Creating Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services), last section: "Services as singletons"), while I need a new instance each time it is injected in a parameter. Am I wrong?

Comment: As I understand it, a factory is a singleton, but a factory can generate a class that can create instances. So the factory would return a reference to the constructor when you inject it, or a function that calls the constructor (without using `new`). But I don't know what's good practice on this TBH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return a class with a factory

```
    .factory('Holder', function() {
        return (function (){
            this.foo = foo;
            this.bar = bar;
        });
    });
```

**Now to use it**

```
.controller('AnyController', ['Holder', function (Holder) {
    var holder = new Holder();
}]);
```

**EDIT**
Use a `factory` instead of a `service`, as suggested in the comments

Comment: then call it factory, if you need new instances each time :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, a factory is a singleton, but a factory can generate a class that can create instances. So the factory would return a reference to the constructor when you inject it, or a wrapper function around the constructor to use it without using `new`:

```
.factory('Holder', function() {
  function Holder(elements) {
    this.elements = elements; 
  }
  Holder.prototype.get = function() {
    return this.elements;
  };
  return function(elements) {
    return new Holder(elements);
  };
})

.controller('Main', function($scope, Holder) {
  var elements = [
    {id: 1, label: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, label: 'bar'}
  ];
  $scope.elements = Holder(elements).get();
});
```